# how to add new column in pyspark and put its values based on other column?

Tags: python, pyspark, unsupervised-learning

i have a data set as follows [nogk is a data frame with mutliple columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br46h.png) .Now i want to create a new column filed_position which takes only 3 values based on position .[the new column can only take 3 values defender,forward or middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmxlC.png).what is the best way to solve .should i use the following code or loop thorough position [code i used ,but i need to get "DEF"for all values which are in DEFENDER list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN1qd.png).

Comment: Instead of link. Can you put your code and a bit context here?

Answer (score 0):

To compare the values with the list provided you need to use isin function
and w=to do multiple compare you need to do when chaining..

```
nogk=nogk.withColumn('Field Position',F.when((F.col('Position').isin(DEFENDER),'DEF').when(
F.col('Position').isin(FORWARD),'FWD').when(
F.col('Position').isin(MIDDLE),'MID').otherwise(F.lit('0'))
```

where DEFENDER, FORWARD and MIDDLE are your list of values to compare.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you still need any help - refer to this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJvG0P2ARcg